# How to reset to a previous git revision?

Tags: git

I'm attempting to reset my git repo to a 2-3 version old commit. I'm trying to do the following:

`git reset 70057f0`

However this gives:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '70057f0': unknown revision or path 
not in the working tree.

Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `git reset --hard 70057f0`

else, use git log, or a GUI to find the correct commit hash, then you can use `reset`.

*NOTE `reset` will only work properly if you havn't already pushed the commits, if you have pushed the commits, you will need to use `revert` which will create a new commit which undoes all previous commits to where you specify.

Comment: I have already pushed the commits. With revert, should I just do `git revert <sha1>`?

Comment: Reset works fine with pushed commits. It, however, requires you to use the `--force` flag when you push your newly reset branch, which can be a headache if you're collaborating with others, depending on people's familiarity with git.

Comment: this is true, but for good practice a reset should really be just for removing local commits... revert is much better because there is a reverse commit there, and it makes sense :)

Comment: Or, alternatively, you can do `git reset --hard 70057f01` and then `git push --force origin/your-branch`. This is rude, but If you care about Git history and no one fetched these commits yet.

Comment: do i have to revert it through the revisions one by one?

Comment: no, git will take care of it, just put the revision you want to revert to in.

Comment: I'm trying `git revert a90b2960a0e5cf9aac0cb20d89510a3beba05ceb` and it says: `error: could not revert a90b296...hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'`

Comment: Yeah resolve the conflicts! use `git status` to show which files are failing to merge, then resolve them.

Comment: I ended up sorting out this issue by checking out to the previous revision.

Answer (score -1):

The SHA1 you gave to git is invalid (it does not exist). Double check it by using `git log` and copy / pasting the SHA1 you want to revert to.